# How to compile a c++ program into shared library, and load it from a c program?

Tags: c, linux, compiler-construction, dynamic-library

I am using gnu c compiler on centos 6, and the c program loads the shared library in the code dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must [declare your function to be useable in C](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html#faq-32.6):

```
extern "C" void foo(int x, char y);
```

Note that you can't do overloading or any of the other features that C++ gives you. (This is because of [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).)